# Deprecated API Android Studio

Tags: java, api, android-studio, deprecated

I have that note when I build my code on Android Studio :

"uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."

I don't understand how I can do this. I'm a beginner on this topic.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You are calling a function that is marked to be outdated, hence the warning. Check your codebase, if you are using an IDE, the offending line of code may be marked.

Comment: Can you paste some more of the error? I get this warning that I think is caused by hilt, but your full error message should tell us.